# Set Internet Explorer 10 to always open in IE9 browsing mode in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I have many clients who are getting IE10 via Windows Update and cant view websites properly.  I have set some of them to use compatibility mode, but this still doesn't work since it is still using IE10.  I need to figure out how to set IE10 to always open in IE9 browsing mode.  I know they can press f12 and change the browser mode there, but this seems to last only for that session.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Real answer: fix the web sites they're visiting. :)

Comment: Lol True Story.  I wish I could, but most of them are medical related sites and they dont support IE10 yet due to "potential security holes"

Comment: Secondary answer: [Prevent IE10 from being download via Windows update.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36512)

Comment: I use Internet Explorer.....to download Chrome.  do these sites function properly on other browsers? can your users use these other browsers?  like say Safari?  I imagine a lot of the users being in the medical field are probably using iPads or Macbooks(or whatever they are called these days)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation) feature of Internet explorer.

Start regedit.exe, go to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
```

or

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
```

create a DWORD `iexplore.exe` and set the value to 9999 (0x270F).

Comment: Holy Cow that worked! Thank you Thank you Thank you!  I've been tearing my hair out all morning trying to fix something that should have been a quick fix!